# slide hide & show text

Tags: javascript, html, css

I want to create an animation where every X seconds the `active`
class is changing to the next `span` inside the `profession-wrapper` span,
in a way that the `developer span` will slide on top of the `active span` in a way
that will show the letters of the new `active span`, slide on top of it while hiding each letter
and when it covers the entire word the `active` class will go to the next span.

I got the `developer span` to slide, and the `active class` to work as they should,
however the `developer span` does not cover the `active span` that it slides on,
and since the length of the text is different for each span the sliding doesn't finish on the end of the word but in a fix place that leaves a lot of empty space between the `|` and the `active span`.

How can I achieve the slide to cover the text it slides on, and make sure that the slide will finish on the end of the new `active` word?

```js
const firstProfession = document.querySelector('.profession-wrapper').firstElementChild;
let professionActive = document.querySelector('.active');

setInterval(() => {
  professionActive.classList.remove('active');
  professionActive.classList.add('inactive');
  if (professionActive.nextElementSibling) {
    professionActive = professionActive.nextElementSibling;
  } else {
    professionActive = firstProfession;
  }
  
  professionActive.classList.remove('inactive');
  professionActive.classList.add('active');
}, 6000);
```

```css
.profession-header {
  display: flex;
  width: 100%;
  position: relative;
}

.profession-wrapper {
  position: relative;
  display: flex;
  padding-right: 7px;
}

.inactive {
  opacity: 0;
  position: absolute;
  overflow: hidden;
  display: inline-block;
}

.active {
  opacity: 1;
  display: inline-block;
  position: relative;
  overflow: hidden;
  width: max-content;
  padding-right: 5px;
}

.developer::before {
  content: '';
  border-left: 2px solid white;
  display: block;
  margin-right: 5px;
  height: 1.5rem;
  position: absolute;
  left: -7px;
}

.developer {
  position: absolute;
  animation: slide-text-in-out 6s ease-in-out infinite;
}

@keyframes slide-text-in-out {
  0% {
    left: 8px;
  }

  45%, 55% {
    left: 50%;
  }

  100% {
    left: 8px;
  }
}
```

```html
<h5 class="profession-header">
  <span class="profession-wrapper">
    <span class="profession active">Web</span>
    <span class="profession inactive">Full Stack</span>
    <span class="profession inactive">Front End</span>
    <span class="profession inactive">Back End</span>
  </span>
  <span class="developer">Developer</span>
</h5>
```

Answer (score 0):

**UPDATED VERSION**

In response to the OP's comment below, here is an updated version of the animation script/css, that respects the width of the profession when animating the `.developer` element.

It works basically the same, but uses CSS `transition` and `transform` instead of `animation` and `left` to move the `.developer` div.

```js
setupProfessionAnim(document.querySelector('.profession-header'));

function setupProfessionAnim(containerEl) {
  let professions = Array.from(containerEl.querySelectorAll('.profession')),
      sliding = containerEl.querySelector('.developer'),
      covered = true; // <-- state tracking variable

  sliding.addEventListener('transitionend', runNextAnimation); // <-- changed event
  runNextAnimation(); // <-- starts the first transition

  function runNextAnimation() {
    let active, next;
    
    covered = !covered; // <-- inverse the state
    if (covered) { // <-- are we in covering mode?
      sliding.style.transform = 'translateX(0)'; // <-- then cover
      return; // <-- and stop further processing
    }
    
    // otherwise

    active = getWithClass(professions, 'active');
    next = active.nextElementSibling ? active.nextElementSibling : professions[0];

    next.classList.add('active'); // <-- switch the .active class
    active.classList.remove('active'); // <-- here, too
    
    sliding.style.transform = 'translateX(' + getWidth(next) + 'px)'; // <-- and let the .developer div uncover
  }
}

function getWithClass(elList, className) {
  return elList.find
    ? elList.find(el => el.classList.contains(className))
    : elList.filter(el => el.classList.contains(className))[0];
}

function getWidth(el) {
  return el.getBoundingClientRect().width;
}
```

```css
.profession-header {
  display: flex;
  width: 100%;
  position: relative;
}

.profession-wrapper {
  position: relative;
  display: flex;
  padding-right: 7px;
}

.profession {
  display: none;
  width: max-content;
  padding-right: 1ex;
}
.profession.active {
  display: block;
}

.developer {
  position: absolute;
  width: 160px; /* adjust if necessary */
  background-color: #fff; /* remove if you like, just for demonstation purposes */
  transform: translateX(0);
  transition: transform 2s ease-in-out 0s;
}
```

```html
<h5 class="profession-header">
  <span class="profession-wrapper">
    <span class="profession active">Web</span>
    <span class="profession inactive">Full Stack</span>
    <span class="profession inactive">Front End</span>
    <span class="profession inactive">Back End</span>
  </span>
  <span class="developer">Developer</span>
</h5>
```

**PREVIOUS VERSION**

You should avoid having an implicit requirement between `setInterval` and CSS animation timings. Instead, use the events a CSS animation fires to switch classes. This makes sure your animation "timelines" cannot get out of sync (another way to view it is that it ensures there's just a *single* timeline instead of *multiple*).

Below is a working example that addresses your problems. Please note the comments I left!

```js
setupProfessionAnim(document.querySelector('.profession-header'));

function setupProfessionAnim(containerEl) {
  let professions = Array.from(containerEl.querySelectorAll('.profession')), // get an array of all professions
      sliding = containerEl.querySelector('.developer'); // get the 'developer' element
  
  sliding.addEventListener('animationiteration', runNextAnimation); // re-execute runNextAnimation whenever an animation iteration finishes
  
  function runNextAnimation() {
    // this actually switches the classes from 'active' to 'inactive' and vice-versa
    let active = getWithClass(professions, 'active'), // get the current 'active' profession
      next = active.nextElementSibling ? active.nextElementSibling : professions[0]; // find next profession
      
    active.classList.replace('active', 'inactive'); // switch!
    next.classList.replace('inactive', 'active');   // here, too!
  }
}

function getWithClass(elList, className) {
  // convenience helper, uses Array.prototype.find if available and falls back to Array.prototype.filter
  return elList.find
    ? elList.find(el => el.classList.contains(className))
    : elList.filter(el => el.classList.contains(className))[0];
}
```

```css
.profession-header {
  display: flex;
  width: 100%;
  position: relative;
}

.profession-wrapper {
  position: relative;
  display: flex;
  padding-right: 7px;
}

.inactive {
  opacity: 0;
  position: absolute;
  overflow: hidden;
  display: inline-block;
  animation: slide-text-out 2s ease-in-out;
}

.active {
  opacity: 1;
  display: inline-block;
  position: relative;
  overflow: hidden;
  width: max-content;
  padding-right: 5px;
  animation: slide-text-in 2s ease-in-out;
}

/* --- removed ---
.developer::before {
  content: '';
  border-left: 2px solid white;
  display: block;
  margin-right: 5px;
  height: 1.5rem;
  position: absolute;
  left: -7px;
}
--- removed --- */

.developer {
  position: absolute;
  /* --- new additions --- */
  width: 160px; /* adjust if necessary */
  border-left: 2px solid white;
  padding-left: 5px;
  background-color: #fff; /* remove if you like, just for demonstation purposes */
  /* --- end new additions --- */
  animation: slide-text-in-out 6s ease-in-out infinite;
}

@keyframes slide-text-in-out {
  0% {
    left: 0;
  }

  45%, 55% {
    left: 50%;
  }

  100% {
    left: 0;
  }
}
```

```html
<h5 class="profession-header">
  <span class="profession-wrapper">
    <span class="profession active">Web</span>
    <span class="profession inactive">Full Stack</span>
    <span class="profession inactive">Front End</span>
    <span class="profession inactive">Back End</span>
  </span>
  <span class="developer">Developer</span>
</h5>
```

Comment: thanks for the comments on the ```JS``` but adding a white background doesn't help me since the background of my page is an image. And also I wanted the sliding to finish on the end of the word, any idea how can I do that?

Comment: @guy I modified my answer with a new version. In regards to the `background-color`: Like my comments said, you can safely remove it if you want.